# How do I pass an OpenCV Mat into a C++ Tensorflow graph?

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow

In Tensorflow C++ I can load an image file into the graph using

```
tensorflow::Node* file_reader =  tensorflow::ops::ReadFile(tensorflow::ops::Const(IMAGE_FILE_NAME, b.opts()),b.opts().WithName(input_name));
tensorflow::Node* image_reader = tensorflow::ops::DecodePng(file_reader, b.opts().WithAttr("channels", 3).WithName("png_reader"));
tensorflow::Node* float_caster = tensorflow::ops::Cast(image_reader, tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, b.opts().WithName("float_caster"));
tensorflow::Node* dims_expander = tensorflow::ops::ExpandDims(float_caster, tensorflow::ops::Const(0, b.opts()), b.opts());
tensorflow::Node* resized = tensorflow::ops::ResizeBilinear(dims_expander, tensorflow::ops::Const({input_height, input_width},b.opts().WithName("size")),b.opts());
```

For an embedded application I would like to instead pass an OpenCV Mat into this graph.

How would I convert the Mat to a tensor that could be used as input to tensorflow::ops::Cast or tensorflow::ops::ExpandDims?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not directly from a CvMat, but you can see an example of how to initialize a Tensor from an in-memory array in the TensorFlow Android example:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0.6.0/tensorflow/examples/android/jni/tensorflow_jni.cc#L173

You would start off by creating a new tensorflow::Tensor object, with something like this (all code untested):

`tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
      tensorflow::TensorShape({1, height, width, depth}));`

This creates a Tensor object with float values, with a batch size of 1, and a size of `width`x`height`, and with `depth` channels. For example a 128 wide by 64 high image with 3 channels would pass in a shape of `{1, 64, 128, 3}`. The batch size is just used when you need to pass in multiple images in a single call, and for simple uses you can leave it as 1.

Then you would get the underlying array behind the tensor using a line like this:

`auto input_tensor_mapped = input_tensor.tensor<float, 4>();`

The `input_tensor_mapped` object is an interface to the data in your newly-created tensor, and you can then copy your own data into it. Here I'm assuming you've set `source_data` as a pointer to your source data, for example:

`const float* source_data = some_structure.imageData;`

You can then loop through your data and copy it over:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    const float* source_row = source_data + (y * width * depth);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        const float* source_pixel = source_row + (x * depth);
        for (int c = 0; c < depth; ++c) {
           const float* source_value = source_pixel + c;
           input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, c) = *source_value;
        }
    }
}
```

There are obvious opportunities to optimize this naive approach, and I don't have sample code on hand to show how to deal with the OpenCV side of getting the source data, but hopefully this is helpful to get you started.

Comment: what is the number of depth in tensorflow::TensorShape for a greyscale image?

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete example to read and feed:

```cpp
Mat image;
image = imread("flowers.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(input_height, input_width), 0, 0, CV_INTER_CUBIC);

int depth = 3;
tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
                                tensorflow::TensorShape({1, image.rows, image.cols, depth}));

for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++) {
        Vec3b pixel = image.at<Vec3b>(y, x);

        input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, 0) = pixel.val[2]; //R
        input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, 1) = pixel.val[1]; //G
        input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, 2) = pixel.val[0]; //B
    }
}

auto result = Sub(root.WithOpName("subtract_mean"), input_tensor, {input_mean});
ClientSession session(root);
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({result}, out_tensors));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had tried to run inception model on the opencv `Mat` file and following code worked for me https://gist.github.com/kyrs/9adf86366e9e4f04addb. Although there are some issue with integration of opencv and  tensorflow. Code worked without any issue for `.png` files but failed to load  `.jpg` and `.jpeg`. You can follow this for more info https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1924

Answer (score 1):

```
Tensor convertMatToTensor(Mat &input)
{
    int height = input.rows;
    int width = input.cols;
    int depth = input.channels();

    Tensor imgTensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({height, width, depth}));

    float* p = imgTensor.flat<float>().data();
    Mat outputImg(height, width, CV_32FC3, p);
    input.convertTo(outputImg, CV_32FC3);

    return imgTensor;
}
```